# How to develop using a Remote Docker Container

Tags: java, eclipse, docker

I have a Linux (CentOS) based development system that is running Docker, and I have several other machines that will be used to develop client and server- side software that will be run in a Docker container. All software will be developed using Eclipse.

I have learned how to access and run remote docker containers from within Eclipse. What I would like to do is set up an environment where developers can write code (for example, server side code) in any language supported by Eclipse (particularly Java or Typescript), compile that code and run/debug it using Eclipse's debugger but within a remote docker container.

I have seen this capability in another IDE. VSCode has that capability for developers writing Python- based microservices. It allowed a team I was working with to write microservice code from within VSCode and actually run debugging sessions using VSCode debugger within a remote Docker container that was running on a shared, secure VM!

Is there a way to do this using Eclipse? If so, how can it be done?